# Using correct class instance when making multiple instances in succession

Tags: python, button, instance, maya

Having an issue with my script when I make multiple tabs in a row. I if I make two tabs and then try to edit the first; it changes the second tab and not the first.

```
import pymel.core as pm
import maya.cmds as cmds
class TabWindow(pm.ui.Window):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(TabWindow, self).__init__()
        self.title = "TabWindow"
        self.tabA = None
        self.tabB = None                      
        self.buildUI()


    def modifySomethingInTabB(self):
        pm.button(label="TestButton", parent=self.tabB)

    def appendJointChain(self, *args):
        print "button pressed"
        self.set_up_Tab()
        self.tool_Tab()



    def fillTabA(self, parent):
        pm.setParent(parent)
        pm.text(label = 'Root Joint Selection', align ='center')
        pm.separator(h=5)
        pm.button(label = 'Add Selector', c=lambda event: self.name_DialogBox())

    def fillTabB(self, parent):    
        pm.setParent(parent)
        pm.text(label = 'FK IK Switch', align ='center')
        pm.separator(h=5)

    def Remove(InstanceName):
        pm.deleteUI(self)


    def buildUI(self):
        tabLayout = None
        children = []
        pm.setUITemplate("DefaultTemplate", pushTemplate=True)
        with pm.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True,width=300) as cl:
            with pm.tabLayout() as tabLayout:
                for childName in ["My Tab A", "My Tab B"]:
                    with pm.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True) as cla:
                        children.append((cla, childName))

        self.fillTabA(children[0][0])
        self.fillTabB(children[1][0])
        self.tabA = children[0][0]
        self.tabB = children[1][0]

        pm.tabLayout(tabLayout, edit=True, tabLabel=children)
        pm.setUITemplate("DefaultTemplate", popTemplate=True)      

    def name_DialogBox(self):
        result = cmds.promptDialog(
            title='Rename Object',
            message='Enter Name:',
            button=['OK', 'Cancel'],
            defaultButton='OK',
            cancelButton='Cancel',
            dismissString='Cancel')

        if result == 'OK':
            self.InstanceName = cmds.promptDialog(query=True, text=True)
            ###Create New Tab using text as name####
            self.appendJointChain()
            return self.InstanceName



    def set_up_Tab(self):

        cmds.frameLayout (width = 300, label = self.InstanceName,  collapse = True, collapsable = True, marginWidth = 5, parent = self.tabA);

        self.nametab =cmds.text(label = self.InstanceName, align ='center')

        self.tsL0 =pm.textFieldButtonGrp(ed=False, adj=1,cal=(1,"left"),cw3=(10,100,25), cl3=("left","left","left") , 
                                    buttonLabel='Root   FK', bc= lambda : self.select_joints_afk())
        self.tsL1 = pm.textFieldButtonGrp(ed=False, adj=1,cal=(1,"left"),cw3=(10,100,25), cl3=("left","left","left") , 
                                    buttonLabel='Wrist   IK',bc= lambda : self.select_joints_aikw())
        self.tsL2 = pm.textFieldButtonGrp(ed=False, adj=1,cal=(1,"left"),cw3=(10,100,25), cl3=("left","left","left") , 
                                    buttonLabel='Elbow IK',bc= lambda : self.select_joints_ikpv())

        pm.separator(h=5)
        pm.button( label = 'Remove ' + self.InstanceName, command = lambda :Remove(), width=100)
        pm.separator

        return self.tsL0, self.tsL1, self.tsL2



    def tool_Tab(self):

        cmds.frameLayout (width = 300, label = self.InstanceName,  collapse = True, collapsable = True, marginWidth = 5, parent = self.tabB);
        cmds.separator(h=5)
        self.row=cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2,width = 300)


        self.IKbutton=cmds.button(label='IK', command = '', width=100)
        self.FKbutton=cmds.button(label='FK', command = '', width=100)
        self.parent=cmds.setParent('..')
        self.row2=cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2,width = 300)

        self.Fk2IK_Button = pm.button(label='FK 2 IK', command = lambda _: self.fk_2_ik(), width=100)
        self.Ik2FK_Button = pm.button(label='IK 2 FK', command = lambda _: self.ik_2_fk(), width=100)

        self.parent

    def select_joints_afk(self):
        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):
            sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
            fkCtrls = cmds.listRelatives(sel, allDescendents=True, type=("transform",'nurbsCurve'))
            self.Fks = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in fkCtrls if nurbsCurve.startswith('FK') & nurbsCurve.endswith('_Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(self.tsL0, edit = True, tx ='' .join(sel),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))
            self.Fks.extend(sel)
            print self.Fks
            return self.Fks,self.tsL0
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], 
                                        defaultButton='Ok', dismissString='No' )


    def select_joints_aikw(self):
        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):

            sel=cmds.ls(selection = True)
            ikwrist = sel
            self.Ikw = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in ikwrist if nurbsCurve.startswith('IK') & nurbsCurve.endswith('Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(self.tsL1, edit = True, tx ='' .join(ikwrist),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))
            cmds.select(ikwrist)
            print self.Ikw
            return self.Ikw
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], defaultButton='Ok', 
                                        dismissString='No' )

    def select_joints_ikpv(self):
        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):
            sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
            ikPvsel = sel
            self.ikpv = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in ikPvsel if nurbsCurve.endswith('Pv_Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(self.tsL2, edit = True, tx ='' .join(ikPvsel),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))        
            cmds.select(ikPvsel)
            print self.ikpv
            return self.ikpv
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], 
                                        defaultButton='Ok', dismissString='No' )

    def ik_2_fk(self):

        #import combined selection list
        match_selection = self.Fks + self.Ikw + self.ikpv
        print("List created" + str(match_selection))



    def fk_2_ik(self):
         #import combined selection list
        match_selection = self.Fks + self.Ikw + self.ikpv
        print("List created" + str(match_selection))

tw = TabWindow()
# if pm.window(tw, exists = True):
#     pm.deleteUI(tw)
tw.show()
```

I'm under the impression that In order to accomplish this I need to have each set of selections be an instance of a class so that I can edit them. With that in mind, I moved the

```
    def select_joints_afk(self):,    def select_joints_aikw(self):, &   def select_joints_ikpv(self):
```

into a Create selectionChains class like so..

```
class Create_Selection_Chains():

    def __init__(self, name ,Fks, Ikw, ikpv):
        self.name=name
        self.Fks = Fks
        self.Ikw = Ikw
        self.ikpv = ikpv
        print  Fks + Ikw + ikpv


    def select_joints_afk(self):
        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):
            sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
            fkCtrls = cmds.listRelatives(sel, allDescendents=True, type=("transform",'nurbsCurve'))
            self.Fks = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in fkCtrls if nurbsCurve.startswith('FK') & nurbsCurve.endswith('_Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(TabWindow().tsL0, edit = True, tx ='' .join(sel),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))
            self.Fks.extend(sel)
            print self.Fks
            return self.Fks 
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], 
                                        defaultButton='Ok', dismissString='No' )

    def select_joints_aikw(self):
        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):

            sel=cmds.ls(selection = True)
            ikwrist = sel
            self.Ikw = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in ikwrist if nurbsCurve.startswith('IK') & nurbsCurve.endswith('Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(Set_up_Tab().tsL1, edit = True, tx ='' .join(ikwrist),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))
            cmds.select(ikwrist)
            print self.Ikw
            return self.Ikw
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], defaultButton='Ok', 
                                        dismissString='No' )

    def select_joints_ikpv(self):
        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):
            sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
            ikPvsel = sel
            self.ikpv = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in ikPvsel if nurbsCurve.endswith('Pv_Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(self.tsL2, edit = True, tx ='' .join(ikPvsel),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))        
            cmds.select(ikPvsel)
            print self.ikpv
            return self.ikpv
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], 
                                        defaultButton='Ok', dismissString='No' )
```

& the instance is created In TabWindow Class method `def appendJointChain(self, *args):`:

```
self.joint_chain_select = Create_Selection_Chains( self, "foo", "bar", "baz")
```

I've made several attempts at this (shown above in Create_Selection_Chains class) but I can't seem to get it right.

```
# Error: AttributeError: file <maya console> line 136: 'TabWindow' object has no attribute 'tsL0' #
# Error: NameError: file <maya console> line 150: global name 'Set_up_Tab' is not defined #
# Error: AttributeError: file <maya console> line 163: Create_Selection_Chains instance has no attribute 'tsL2' #
```

I think I might need to have the tabs I create in the UI be either thier own class or part of Create_Selection_Chains class but I'm really unsure at this point.
Could someone explain what is going on and how I might be able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to give you some advice since your code is somewhat chaotic. Since you are creating one interface and you use pymel anyway I recommend to keep everything within one single class and build everyting in this class. e.g. you want to create a window with two tabs could work this way:

```
class TabWindow(pm.ui.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TabWindow, self).__init__()
        self.title = "TabWindow"
        self.tabA = None
        self.tabB = None
        self.buildUI()

    def createSelecttionChain(self):
        pass

    def modifySomethingInTabB(self):
        pm.button(label="TestButton", parent=self.tabB)

    def pushButton(self, *args):
        print "button pressed"
        self.modifySomethingInTabB()

    def fillTabA(self, parent):
        pm.setParent(parent)
        pm.button(label="PushMe", c=self.pushButton)

    def buildUI(self):
        tabLayout = None
        children = []
        pm.setUITemplate("DefaultTemplate", pushTemplate=True)
        with pm.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True) as cl:
            with pm.tabLayout() as tabLayout:
                for childName in ["My Tab A", "My Tab B"]:
                    with pm.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True) as cla:
                        children.append((cla, childName))

        self.fillTabA(children[0][0])
        self.tabA = children[0][0]
        self.tabB = children[1][0]

        pm.tabLayout(tabLayout, edit=True, tabLabel=children)
        pm.setUITemplate("DefaultTemplate", popTemplate=True)      

tw = TabWindow()
tw.show()
```

Then you can add your tools step by step. This way the code is much better readable and much better to maintain. And errors are easier to find.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize how confusing it was. I was so focused on just trying to get it to work. You wouldn't happen to know how I would go about parenting new new tab content with this setup would you? like if I were to make a ```def fillTabB``` and want that parented to ```fillTabA``` when ```pushbutton()``` is run?

Comment: So you want to add content to "My Tab B" if the button is pressed? This needs a slightly different setup. Since you want to access the tab it is useful to have a variable declated in the init which can be accessed by all methods, I'll try to edit the answer so it reflects your question.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question using what you and DrWeeny have provided so I hope this is more readable and better illustrates my issue

Answer (score 0):

You should provide an executable code.
Here is an advance example for managing your ui.
It is based on your code and what I did understand from it :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import re

global myUI
myUI = {}

# please use for def lower case for the first letter and upper case for class
def nameDialogBox(*args):
    print('prompt')

class TabSet(object):
    # don't put self here, they are implicit
    gtF0 = []
    gtF1 = []
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.name = parent

    def addTab(self, name):
        nb = cmds.tabLayout(self.name, q=True, tabLabelIndex=True)
        index = len(nb) +  1

        myUI['tab{}'.format(index)] = cmds.columnLayout(p=self.name)

        cmds.tabLayout( self.name, q=True, tabLabel=True)

        cmds.tabLayout( self.name, edit=True, tabLabel=[myUI['tab{}'.format(index)], name])

        return myUI['tab{}'.format(index)]

    def listTabs(self):

        keys = [i for i in myUI.keys() if re.match('^tab\d+$', i)]
        keys = sorted(keys)
        output = [myUI[k] for k in keys]

        return output

def toolWidget(parent=str):
    wgt = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, p=parent)
    cmds.button(l='WidgetButton1', p=wgt)
    cmds.button(l='WidgetButton2',p=wgt)
    cmds.button(l='WidgetButton3',p=wgt)
    return wgt

def testWin():

    cmds.window( widthHeight=(200, 150) )
    form = cmds.columnLayout()
    myUI['tabLayout1'] = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=5, innerMarginHeight=5, p=form)

    myUI['tab1'] = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, p=myUI['tabLayout1'])
    myUI['tab1_button1'] = cmds.button(p=myUI['tab1'])
    cmds.button(p=myUI['tab1'])
    cmds.button(p=myUI['tab1'])

    myUI['tab2'] = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, p=myUI['tabLayout1'])
    cmds.button(p=myUI['tab2'])
    cmds.button(p=myUI['tab2'])
    cmds.button(p=myUI['tab2'])

    cmds.tabLayout( myUI['tabLayout1'], edit=True, tabLabel=((myUI['tab1'], 'One'), (myUI['tab2'], 'Two')) )

    cmds.showWindow()


testWin()

# create a tab
tabMan = TabSet(myUI['tabLayout1'])
new_tab = tabMan.addTab('myAddition')

# update the color
cmds.button(myUI['tab1_button1'], e=True, bgc=[.1,1,.5])

# adding a widget to the tab3 we just created
myUI['tab3_widget1'] = toolWidget(new_tab)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm not quite sure what you mean by providing an executable code. Was this not running for you at all?

Comment: if you open a fresh maya and run what you give us, it doesn't run

Comment: Thank you!I have edited my question using haggi kreys template so I'm hoping this version is less confusing. This should run in a fresh maya

Comment: instead of using a dictionnary you can inherit from your classes. otherwise i think my answer can help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got it! As far as adding to the UI is concerned I was able to get this working by
simply setting the parents by using the instance of the UI that was created with `tw = TabWindow` when I parent my tabs it should be `parent = tw.tabA` and `parent = tw.tabB`

I really should have read through this more carefully